# 3D vector field gnuplot

Tags: vector, plot, 3d, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a vector field and i Would like to have some help:

1. I would like to have a 3D GRID
2. i would like to know how can i draw a border of specific dimension
3. How can i define a palette like a gradient based on a specific component of a vector field,
   i.e I have a vector field like the one in figure, I'd like the vectors to change color from       red to blu depending on the magnitude of the y-component let's say .

I know it's a lot but i really need help
[my 3D plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Dof.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Not sure what you mean by a 3D grid.

2) The border dimensions are set by xrange, yrange, and zrange.  You can remove the extra space below the minimum z using

```
  set xyplane 0
```

To change the size on the page, you can change the 3rd and 4th parameters of the `set view` command:

```
  set view rotx, rotz, scale1, scale2
```

It is easiest to adjust these by click-and-drag with the middle mouse button and then either write down the scale values shown in the plot window or issue the `show view` command.

3) Red to blue palette mapped to y coordinate (column 2 in your plot):

```
  set palette defined (0 "red", 1 "blue")
  set style data vector
  splot "resampled.odt" using 1:2:3:($4*factor):($5*factor):($6*factor):2 lc palette
```

Comment: Oh thwnks really helpful, with 3d grid i mean a grid dividing the 3d space in cubic cell with dotted line